# How to order data to the right instead of to the bottom in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, pivot

let say i have this data on my table

```
select * from user.weekly_job;
```

got :

```
Staff | JobType
A | 1
A | 3
A | 5
A | 2
A | 3
B | 3
B | 5
B | 2
B | 2
```

but i need all data from staff which contained the occurence of each job type like this :

```
Staff | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
A     | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1
B     | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1
```

how to do this with oracle query?

Comment: i have more than 10thousand data after grouping by each job type, but php need long time to do this job, so i need to try it in oracle way first for comparing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed count of JobType values:

```
select STAFF,
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobType=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1",
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobType=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "2",
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobType=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "3",
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobType=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "4",
       SUM(CASE WHEN JobType=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "5"
FROM t
GROUP BY STAFF
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9c23/3)